# QLabel doesn't show multiple digit integer

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlabel

I want to display an integer in a `QLabel` and it work fine. But, when my integer has 2 or more digits, it only display the first digit and not the others.
I have try this :

```
shotsLabel->setText(QString::number(mTotalShots));
```

And this :

```
shotsLabel->setNum(mTotalShots);
```

In the two cases, it work with integer from 0 to 9, but next, it only show the first digit but not the others. For example, if I want to display 56, it only display 5.

Comment: It seems like a size problem. Did you arrange your widgets in a layout? Increase your label width maybe it's the cause.

Comment: try use `shotsLabel->adjustSize()` after setText

Comment: Maybe issue with layout and/or size policy. Question doesn't show enough code, so hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
```

Please try to use this